# Include native libraries with mobile chrome app

Tags: android, cordova, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, cordova-plugins

For the purpose of simplicity as native library I would like to use hello-jni from the `Android NDK` samples. We trigger `ndk-build` and it builds an nice libs folder with the .so files we want.

I have a trivial chrome application which I am wrapping with the `cca` tool in order to build my android mobile app.

I have build a `cordova` plugin which loads the native libraries and provide an interface for the methods of it. In a simple cordova application build with `cordova` works just fine.

I am adding the plugin to my mobile app but when I build the mobile app with `cca build android` or when I run it on my device `cca run android` what I receive in my device logs is

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.HelloJni/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libhello-jni.so"
```

Is `cca` capable of building in that fashion? or what an alternative could be?